# Singleton objects with prototype in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, singleton, javascript-objects

I came across below code written in node which I am trying to understand. There is a method `process` attached to prototype as well as to the object itself. Whats the difference? I understand the approach is used to have singleton instances for the object. However would like further explanation or reference to how this works.

```
var singleton;
var MyObj = function(opts) {//code}
MyObj.prototype = {
  process: function() {//code}  
}
MyObj.process = function process() {
  singleton.process();
}
MyObj.init = function init(opts) {
  singleton = new MyObj(opts);
}
module.exports = MyObj;
```

Comment: It looks like you're giving you the option of using it as a singleton or a constructor. Whichever works better for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain each block of code:

```
var singleton;
```

This variable is declared in the module but not exported. This means it is private to the module and exists within a closure.

```
var MyObj = function(opts) { /* code */ }
```

This is the constructor.

```
MyObj.prototype = {
  process: function() {//code}  
}
```

Every instance created using the `MyObj` constructor is given a `process` method.

```
MyObj.process = function process() {
  singleton.process();
}
```

This method exists on the prototype itself. When called, it executes the `process` method of the `singleton` object. Because the `singleton` object 
is private to this module, every call to `MyObj.process` executes the `.process` method of the same `singleton` object.

```
MyObj.init = function init(opts) {
  singleton = new MyObj(opts);
}
```

The `init` method is used to create an instance of the `MyObj` prototype. This instance is assigned to the `singleton` object. The `singleton` object is private to the module so every call to `MyObj.init` manipulates the same `singleton` instance, effectively overwriting the object that was previously stored in it. This ensures that the `singleton` object is always an instance of `MyObj`.

```
module.exports = MyObj;
```

The constructor is exported here. Note that the `singleton` object is not exported.

**In summary**

`(new MyObj()).process()` and `MyObj.process()` perform the same function because they use the same `singleton` instance. You can read about singletons in NodeJS [here](http://thenodeway.io/posts/designing-singletons/) and [here](https://medium.com/@iaincollins/how-not-to-create-a-singleton-in-node-js-bd7fde5361f5#.9lqrgndsr)